# How to read Android Market comments?

Tags: android, comments, google-play

Reading the users' feedbacks about my apps is really important, but in my phone I can only read those written in the language of my phone (Italian).

Is there a way to read all of them?

A program for PC or a website could be a good solution.

(Actually Cyrket and AndroLib read comments directly from the market, but sometimes they don't update or are very slow).

Thanks.

Comment: +1: I have been using Cyrket, but I am not very happy with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had a great influence on Google, since now we can read comments directly on the Android Market Developers dashboard.

Haha, great!! :) :) ... it took only 3 days!!